# Looking for a bounded continuous $o(1)$ function on $]0, +\infty[$ that is not in $L^{p}(]0, +\infty[)$ for all $0 < p < +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am looking for a bounded continuous function $f \colon ]0, +\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = o(1)$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f \notin L^{p}(]0, +\infty[)$ for all $ 0 < p < +\infty$.

My closest candidate was $x \mapsto 1/x$, which satisfies all conditions but the boundedness on the given interval.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What about $f(x)=c$ ?

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti  Thk you. It is a pity that a constant function is not $o(1)$.

Comment: Assuming you exclude $p = +\infty$, take something with a logarithmic decay at $\infty$.

Comment: Shift the function you found so that its singularity (now at $x=0$) goes to $x=-1$. That point is outside the domain you are considering, that is, $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I tried such one :). $x \mapsto 1/(x+1)$, for example. But if I was not mistaken, it is $L^{p}$ for quite many $p$. Let me check again anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's in $L^p$ for $p > 1$.

Comment: But the principle is good. Assuming $\alpha>0$, the function $(1+x)^{-\alpha}$ is in $L^p(0, \infty)$ for all $\frac{1}{\alpha}<p\le \infty$. Taking smaller values of  $\alpha$ you can construct examples that are in "quite a few" $L^p$ spaces, thanks to the weak decay at infinity. To obtain the example you need, consider the next step of weak decay: a logarithmic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\ln 2} & x < 2 \\
\frac{1}{\ln(x)} & x \ge 2
\end{cases}.$$

$f$ is in no $L^p$-space for $p < \infty$, since
$$\int_2^t \frac{1}{\ln(x)^p} \, dx = \int_{\ln(2)}^{\log(t)} y^{-p} e^y \, dy$$
and $y^{-p}e^y \to \infty$ for $y \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have played with such one; obviously I made mistakes in analyzing the integral, haha. Thk you :).